# Text-to-speech in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, text-to-speech

Does anybody know of an API or plug-in that can perform text-to-speech for .aspx files, i've seen some but the majority are trying to make me pay to redirect the visitor to their site where it will read out the content, like this: http://www.ispeech.org/api

If anybody is aware of something and could point me in the right direction it would be great. Just to clarify, I would want it to work like this:

```
<html>
     <head>
          <title>My page</title>
     </head>
     <body>
          <p>This is my page</p>
     </body>
</html>
```

I would only like the api to read out the "This is my page" element, and if possible the title of the page. So does anybody know of anything, and just so you know, i'm developing this site within Visual Studios 2010.

Thanks again guys.

P.S.: If possible, I would like it to work within the page, not redirect to another site or window.

Comment: cant you parse the asp file and then have whatever you want read out? If you can, your options for TTS engines will increase.

Comment: I could do but its not specifically for me, its incase a user visits the site, without tts software, and would like to use it, because of the nature of the website it would be fitting to have one on the site itself, rather than relying on users to have one already, silly I know, but its just a thought really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found something:
http://www.speechapi.com/apis/javascript/